# Visible value rows in grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, propertygrid

I have a Property Grid with some fields (textfield, numberfield). I want, that they all are to be visible immediately when the table is opened. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Here's grid

```
var propGrid = new Ext.grid.PropertyGrid({
        url: 'fill-template-form-panel-id',
        id: 'propGrid',
        autoFill: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        width: '100%',
        disableSelection : true,
        source: {
        "name": "Vasya",
        "surname": "Pupkin"
},
        style: 'margin:0 auto;margin-top:10px;'
      });
```

Comment: They? Tab? I don't see a tab and don't know what you mean by they.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the example below the renderTo property is set to render it immediately.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
    title: 'Properties Grid',
    width: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    source: {
        "(name)": "My Object",
        "Created": Ext.Date.parse('10/15/2006', 'm/d/Y'),
        "Available": false,
        "Version": 0.01,
        "Description": "A test object"
    }
});
```

Notice that you should not use renderTo() when the propertygrid is a child of a container. This because the container then is responsible for rendering it.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.property.Grid.html#cfg-renderTo